# Can't call attribute of class within the class itself in Python 3.6.5

Tags: python, python-3.x

Apologies if the following question has already been posed on StackOverflow, but I couldn't find it posted here, nor was I able to find an answer after some time spent Googling.

My question is as follows. I would expect the following Python code,

```
class MNL(object):

    def load_data():
        r = 3 + 4
        return r

    def load_data_wrapper():
        s = load_data()
        return s
```

to return the output "7". Instead I get the error message "NameError: name 'load_data' is not defined".

If I change the second-to-last line to "s = self.load_data()" I get "NameError: name 'self' is not defined". For reference, I'm using Python 3.6.5.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: You need to change it to `def load_data_wrapper(self):` before you can use `self.load_data()`.

Comment: Tried this already. I then get the error message "
TypeError: load_data_wrapper() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'" once I call "MNL.load_data_wrapper()"

Answer (score 2):

Any reference to object methods or attributes in Python requires the `self` keyword, and it should always be the first parameter of any class method. To fix your code, it would be:

```
class MNL(object):

    def load_data(self):
        r = 3 + 4
        return r

    def load_data_wrapper(self):
        s = self.load_data()
        return s
```

The `self` parameter receives the reference of the object.

Comment: Cf. my comment above, executing this code and calling "MNL.load_data_wrapper()" I get the error message "TypeError: load_data_wrapper() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'". Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Are you calling the function from a class object? You should have something like: `mnl = MNL()` `mnl.load_data_wrapper()`

Comment: If you call `MNL.load_data_wrapper()` you are referencing the class itself, not an object of the class, firstly you need to instantiate an object of the class

Comment: Indeed, calling "mnl = MNL().load_data_wrapper()" I get the desired output "7". That solved my problem, thanks for your help!

Comment: You can also make the methods class methods or static methods. If you do so, instantiation is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the questions I see in the comments I wanted to offer up some changes to the code.

```
class MNL(object):
    @staticmethod
    def load_data():
        r = 3 + 4
        return r

    @classmethod
    def load_data_wrapper(cls):
        s = cls.load_data()
        return s

    def load_data_wrapper2():
        return MNL.load_data()
```

This utilizes [Class and Static methods](https://realpython.com/instance-class-and-static-methods-demystified/) These do not operate on "self" but are methods that you still want to tie to a singular class

```
>>> MNL.load_data_wrapper2()
7
>>> MNL.load_data_wrapper()
7
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. However, curiously enough, calling "MNL.load_data_wrapper2()" I get the error message "TypeError: load_data() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'". On the other hand, calling "MNL.load_data_wrapper()" I get the desired output "7". Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @user810643 odd, I can not reproduce that issue. There is no argument in that method so that error is perplexing

Comment: Defining `load_data_wrapper2` without any arguments will only work if you use `@staticmethod`.

Comment: My bad! I rebooted the Jupyter kernel, and now both "MNL.load_data_wrapper2()" and "MNL.load_data_wrapper()" give the desired output "7".